# Makefile failing on last file

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use a makefile to make some tests for my other program.

```
DIFF=$(TXT_FILES:$(TESTS_DIR)/%.txt=$(DIFF_DIR)/%.dif), $(STDIN_FILES:$(TESTS_DIR/%.stdin=$(DIFF_DIR)%.dif)

$(DIFF_DIR)/%.dif: $(TESTS_DIR)/%.txt $(DIFF_DIR)/%.out
    ./03uzduotis/getfasta $< | diff $(DIFF_DIR)/$*.out - > $@

$(DIFF_DIR)/%.dif: $(TESTS_DIR)/%.stdin $(DIFF_DIR)/%.out
    cat $< | ./03uzduotis/getfasta - | diff $(DIFF_DIR)/$*.out - > $@
```

The problem I'm having is that when I launch the makefile, it goes through all test files except the last one, citing "There is no rule to make Test1.dif required by "tests""

I have checked by removing some Test files that it indeed dies on the last file no matter which file is the last one.

Comment: Check the number of "f"s in "diff". I suspect you have a typo in the original code (as the posted code reads ".dif", but the error message refers to ".diff").

Comment: That extra f there is just my keyboard messing up.

Comment: When you ask for a problem about makefile. Please, add all makefile and files project organization.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Preparing a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a vital coding skill, and helps a lot here. You're already partway there, now just reduce the list of test files to one file, eliminate the %.dif rule you think is unnecessary, and give us the whole (small) picture.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like these an extraneous comma in here:

```
DIFF=$(TXT_FILES:$(TESTS_DIR)/%.txt=$(DIFF_DIR)/%.dif), $(STDIN_FILES:$(TESTS_DIR/%.stdin=$(DIFF_DIR)%.dif)
```

`$(DIFF)` is going to look like `ddir/one.dif ddir/two.dif, ddir/stdin1.dif`  The middle file name there really does have a comma as part of the name.  Lists in Make are separated by whitespace, not commas.

I suspect your error message isn't exact, since from your example all filenames should have been prefixed with `$(DIFF_DIR)/`, and the comma is the error message too.

You've also got a missing `)` and a missing `/` in the substitution `$(TESTS_DIR/%.stdin=$(DIFF_DIR)%.dif`.  Likely part of that is a typo in your question as the unbalanced parenthesizes would cause a parse error.